# Three.js "black" transparency on material

Tags: canvas, three.js, blender

I have problem with transparent UV map in threejs. When I set texture in blender and I click "render" everything it's ok
[image: Blender photo with material color]

but when I load model in threejs by JSONloader the black background load under PNG texture instead blender's material color.
[image: Threejs photo with black background]

How can I delete this black background in threejs and use blender material color?

Here is my code

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
  var guiControls, controls, stats, axis, lightHelper;
  var sceneBackground;
  var spotLight;
  var cube, ground, toursKnot, text;
  var groundMaterial, boxMaterial, torMaterial, textMaterial;
  var groundGeometry, boxGeometry, torGeometry, textGeometry;
  var SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;


  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load('models/CupME9.json', addModel);

  function addModel(geometry, materials){
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    model.scale.set(1,1,1);
    model.position.set(5,2,0);
    model.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(model);
  }


  function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 500);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true });



    sceneBackground = renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;


  //Controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change', render);

  //add helpers
    axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);
    scene.add(axis);


  //grid

    color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
    lineColor = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
    grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50,20,color,lineColor);
    scene.add(grid);

  //camera
    camera.position.set(15,12,10);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    guiControls = new function(){
      this.rotationX = 0.0;
      this.rotationY = 0.0;
      this.rotationZ = 0.0;

      this.lightX = 10;
      this.lightY = 10;
      this.lightZ = 15;
      this.intensity = 1;
      this.distance = 0;
      this.angle = 1.570;
      this.exponent = 0;
      this.shadowCameraNear = 1;
      this.shadowCameraFar = 100;
      this.shadowCameraFov = 50;
      this.shadowCameraVisible = true;
      this.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
      this.shadowMapHeigh = 1024;
      this.shadowBias = 0;
      this.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
      this.target = 'cube';
    }

  //lights
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambient);

    spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(10,10,15);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.left = -500;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.right = 500;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.top = 500;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
    spotLight.intensity = guiControls.intensity;
    spotLight.distance = guiControls.distance;
    spotLight.shadow.bias = guiControls.shadowBias;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = guiControls.shadowCameraFov;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.near = guiControls.shadowCameraNear;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.far = guiControls.shadowCameraFar;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.visible = guiControls.shadowCameraVisible;
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = guiControls.shadowMapWidth; // default is 512
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = guiControls.shadowMapHeigh;
    spotLight.name = 'Spot light';

    lightHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( spotLight.shadow.camera )
    scene.add(lightHelper);
    scene.add(spotLight);

  //Plane
    groundGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(40,0,40);
    groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xa0adaf,
      shininess: 150,
      specular: 0xffffff,
      flatShading : true
    });
    ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeometry, groundMaterial);
    ground.castShadow = false;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(ground);



    var datGUI = new dat.GUI();

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationX', 0, 1);
    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationY', 0, 1);
    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'rotationZ', 0, 1);
    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightX',-60,180);
    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightY',0,180);
    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'lightZ',-60,180);

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'target', ['cube', 'torusKnot','text']).onChange(function(){
        if (guiControls.target == 'cube'){
            spotLight.target =  cube;
        }
        else if (guiControls.target == 'torusKnot'){
            spotLight.target =  toursKnot;
        }
        else if (guiControls.target == 'text'){
            spotLight.target =  text;
        }
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'intensity', 0.01, 5).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.intensity = value;
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'distance', 0, 1000).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.distance = value;
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'angle', 0.001, 1.570).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.angle = value;
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'exponent', 0, 50).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.exponent = value;
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraNear', 0 , 100).name("Near").onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.camera.near = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      lightHelper.update();
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraFar', 0 , 100).name("Far").onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.camera.far = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      lightHelper.update();
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraFov', 0 , 100).name("Fov").onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      lightHelper.update();
    });

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowCameraVisible').onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.camera.visible = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      //lightHelper.update();
    });
    //datGUI.close();

    datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowBias', 0 , 1).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.bias = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      lightHelper.update();
    });

    /*datGUI.add(guiControls, 'shadowDarkness', 0 , 1).onChange(function(value){
      spotLight.shadow.camera.darkness = value;
      spotLight.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });*/
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

    $("#webGL-container").append(stats.domElement);


  }




  function render(){

    spotLight.position.x = guiControls.lightX;
    spotLight.position.y = guiControls.lightY;
    spotLight.position.z = guiControls.lightZ;

  }



  function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    stats.update();
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
  }

  init();
  animate();


  $(window).resize(function(){
    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my workaround here too in case others come across this (originally posted on [Github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12148)). Even though it doesn't work in this case (OP is adding the texture dynamically and needs to set the background texture seperately), in any case where you want the background color to blend with the texture this should work.

**Workaround:**

*Originally done in 3DS Max but should be similar in any modelling software that supports UV Unwrapping*.

Use UV unwrapping to map your model.

Map the polygons where you want the texture to show as normal - that is, get the model to the point where the texture looks the way it currently does the screenshot above, with the black bars around the texture.

Then map all of the rest of the polygons to a small patch of the background colour of the texture.

This is probably best practice anyway, since otherwise it's hard to make the colour of the rest of your model blend with the background colour of your texture